# Automatic Sorting of Rows Based on Multiple Criteria and the Final Column not Blank

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am a project manager, and I have a spreadsheet used to assign different tasks to different team members. Here is a picture of what the spreadsheet looks like: [Task Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsjDt.png)

Each "box," or blank area below each individual, should have information about different tasks. Here is an example picture of what it might look like [Example of Tasks for one Team Member](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15r1h.png)

Here is what each column means:
**Project**: Name of Project Task is associated with
**Due Date**: Date at which task is due by (If the due date has passed, the date will turn red) **Project Manager**: Name of Project Manager assigned to the project the task is associated with **Notes**: General area that can provide a basic description of task
**Scope**: Difficulty of the task. It is measured on a scale of 0 - 5, with 5 being the most difficult
**Priority**: Order of importance. It is measured on a scale of 1 - 5 with 5 being the most difficult (If priority is a 4 or a 5, the project name and description will turn red to emphasize importance)
**Status**: A one-to two-word description as to what is currently happening with the project (These include: Assigned, At Print, Blockage, Completed, In Planning, In Progress, In Review, On Hold, Ongoing)Each "box," or blank area below each individual, should have information about different tasks. Here is an example picture of what it might look like

Currently, I have each section automatically sorting based on Priority, Due Date, and Status (In that order), as can be seen in the code below:

```
function onEdit(event){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var wss = ss.getSheetByName('Staff');
  copy1Sort(wss);
  copy2Sort(wss);
}
//Staff Tab-Copy Column-Sorts Task Rows
   function copy1Sort(wss){ 
      var range = wss.getRange(4,1,9,7);
      range.sort([
        {column: 6, ascending: false},
        {column: 2, ascending: true},
        {column: 7, ascending: true}
      ]);
   }
   function copy2Sort(wss){ 
      var range = wss.getRange(15,1,9,7);
      range.sort([
        {column: 6, ascending: false},
        {column: 2, ascending: true},
        {column: 7, ascending: true}
      ]);
   }
```

I have not shown the sorting codes for all the different "boxes" for space.

**My question is how can I make it so that a row will not sort unless its status (column 7 in this case) is not blank**. I ask because I don't want the row to sort while I am filling out the information, but I still want the rows sorted based on Priority, Due Date, and Status (In that order). Please let me know if I need to explain this further.

I have tried ChatGPT and using a version of IF functions, but neither worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function onEdit(e){
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Staff" && e.range.columnstart == 7 && e.value)  {
    copy1Sort(sh);
    copy2Sort(sh);
  }
}
```

I wouldn't use tables.  I would just put each person on a separate sheet

Comment: Cooper, thank you for responding to my question! I agree that it would normally be better to put each person on a separate sheet. However, I have 23 people that go on this staff sheet, so it wouldn't be optimal to have 23 different sheets. I don't quite understand the answer you provided. I tried plugging in what you have multiple different ways and I cannot get it to work. Could you please explain a little bit further? I apologize as I am merely an amatuer with Apps Script

Comment: onEdit() runs when you edit the Staff sheet in the status column